# Installing Chrome extension via zip, requires App Runtime for Chrome: 'import' extension is not installed

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension, dependencies, installation, google-chrome-arc

We are releasing an Android app for Chromebook. This has to be available as a file download (i.e. flash drive, private login) and not through the Chrome Web Store.

ARC Welder gave me the Chrome Extension `zip` based on the original Android App `apk`. The `zip` easily installed on a Chromebook which has ARC Welder, Evernote or one of the other Android-on-Chrome apps; because the Chrome App Store would have pre-installed the App Runtime for Chrome.

If those apps are removed, and my `zip` becomes the first app to require the App Runtime for Chrome, I get this error

> **Error Loading Extension**
>
> Failed to load extension from: /tmp/MyApp_RanDoM
> 'import' extension is not installed.

Followed by some JSON which looks like the manifest. There is an `import` line which has the key of the dependency I'm looking for.

```
...
"import": [{"ID": "mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc"}],
...
```

To prevent this error for new users, I would rather not require them to install ARC Welder, Evernote, etc.

How can I either

- obtain the App Runtime for Chrome zip so that they can install the App Runtime manually, or
- provide a way for them to download ARC Welder without any of the apps it relies upon

This is to avoid publishing the app through the Chrome Web Store. I am considering making them take this route, but if we could distribute file(s) by a more traditional means that would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the web store, one can install just the dependency, without the ARC Welder or any other reliant app. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-runtime-for-chrome-be/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc

Comment: The link is not working anymore, do you know any other way to install that dependency?

Comment: Found the official open source repository and the related releases: https://bitbucket.org/vladikoff/archon/downloads/?tab=tags